# Extreme values of a function with conditions

Tags: optimization

What is a way to find extreme values of a function $u(x,y,z)=xy+yz+xz$ with conditions $x+y=2, y+z=1$?

Comment: You can turn $u(x,y,z)$ into a $1$ variable function using the substitutions $x=2-y,z=1-y$, and differentiate to find the maximum.

Comment: Or note that $xy+yz+xz=(x+y)(y+z)-y^2=(2)(1)-y^2$.

Comment: So, from this I get that $y=0, x=2, y=1$ and extreme value is 2?

Comment: Yes (I think you meant $z$).

Comment: yes, sorry, z=1 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$u(x,y,z)=(2-y)y+y(1-y)+(2-y)(1-y)=y(2+1-1-2)+y^2(-1-1+1)+2=2-y^2$$
Alternately, $$u(x,y,z)=(x+y)(z+y)-y^2=2-y^2$$

So the minimum is when $y=0$.

Using Lagrange multipliers,

$$g_1(x,y,z)=x+y-2=0$$
$$g_2(x,y,z)=y+z-1=0$$
$$u(x,y,z)=xy+yz+xz$$

$$\nabla u= \lambda _1 \nabla g_1+\lambda _2 \nabla g_2$$
$$(y+z,x+z,x+y)= a (1,1,0)+b (0,1,1)$$
Giving
$$y+z=a$$
$$x+z=a+b$$
$$x+y=b$$
Substituting:
$$x+z=x+2y+z$$
$$y=0$$

Comment: But is there a way to solve this using Lagrange's equations?

Comment: See http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~klein/papers/lagrange-multipliers.pdf page 5 'More dimensions'.

Comment: This was easy, thank you :)

Comment: Thank you too, I had to learn multiple Lagrange multipliers to answer this.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $2 = (x+y)(y+z) = y^2 + xy + yz + zx = y^2 + u(x,y,z)$

Hence, $u(x, y, z) \leq 2$, with equality if and only if $y=0$ (and hence $x=2, z=1$).